# upload to ftp folder with indesign script

Tags: javascript, ftp, binary, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am using indesign CC 2014
I have embedded `"FTPConnection.jsx"` that "Peter Torpey" wrote. then I wrote these codes to upload files to my server. Everything works fine, however files do not open correctly. I tried to open them with Notepad++ and I saw that while uploading files, the jsx changes them.

```
var ftp=new FTPConnection(false);
var acik=ftp.open("192.168.0.1","21","username","password");
if(acik==true){ftp.put(File(myFilePath),"images/1.png");}
ftp.close();
```

this is sample of original image:

> ‰PNG 
>       IHDR  q  Ò   üÇF      pHYs  =5  =5ùäğ]    IDATxÚìİ1¶«<£&è3OÁ#¨µ<
>   <ç7òH+tÚ!Sğ*prà´C¦@ÒA‡»Ïù›ó—?~ÀHHì§ÖzÖ­{¿³÷!  éEˆ_???¿    Ø6…
>   Ä   @ˆ    Ä   @ˆ   €   @ˆ   €    !   €    !   €    !
>   B    !    B    „8    B    „8    q    „8    q    „8    q    â
>   q    â     Ä   â     Ä   â     Ä   @ˆ
>   Ä•ï×¯ê·çoş—£2Ùõµ¡}úı¦p›Ød]ˆ=¶¥uÃ=ˆ½÷óúÇı6\V—Ş

this is after upload:

> ıPNG
>
> ```
> IHDR  q  ı   ııFı     pHYs  =5  =5ııı]    IDATxııı1ıı<ı&ı3Oı#ıı<ı
> ```
>
> <ı7ıH+tı!Sı*prııCı@ıAııııııı?~ıHHııızıı{ııı!  ıEı_???ı    ı6ı
>   ı   @ı    ı   @ı   ı   @ı   ı    !   ı    !   ı    !
>   B    !    B    ı8    B    ı8    q    ı8    q    ı8    q    ı
>   q    ı     ı   ı     ı   ı     ı   @ı
>   ıııııııııoııı2ııııı}ıııpııd]ı=ııuı=ıııııııı6\Vıı

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'd recommend trying is to call

```
ftp.setEncodingBinary();
```

before the call to put().

FTP supports two modes of transfer: ASCII and binary. In ASCII mode, the default, only seven bits per character are transmitted. This is sufficient for standard ASCII-encoded text files. For files with multi-byte encodings and for binary files, the binary FTP mode is required.